# How to link custom static library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I'm making a static library for myself to use when I make games/simulators in c++ OpenGL freeglut. I am calling this library GLUtils. It adds `struct Vector` and `struct Color` and `namespace GL` containing methods such as `void GL::drawShape(Vector *points, Color *colors, int size)` among others. I am compiling GLUtils with the static version of freeglut in Visual Studio 2017 and it compiles fine, when I compile my test usage it compiles fine, and when I ran it it worked fine until I added the opengl stuff. The test still compiled fine but it crashed on load with `Application failed to start properly` and when I went to debug it, it crashed before main was loaded up. Using Dependency Walker and opening up test.exe the only thing showing up red is kernel32.dll under freeglut.dll yet the kernel32.dll dependency is satisfied, and GLUtils.lib isn't on the list(but I think that's because it's static).

Even when I comment out the implementations in GLUtils.cpp and leave the bodies as

```
void GL::drawShape(Vector * points, ColorRGBA * colors, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //glColor4f(colors[i].r, colors[i].g, colors[i].b, colors[i].a);
        //glVertex3f(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
    }
}
```

Test.exe still crashes with the same error.

How am I suppose to link GLUtils.lib and freeglut.lib to Test.exe?

Comment: Use #pragma comment(lib, "GLUtils.lib") and do the same for freeglut too

Comment: in Test.cpp or whatever file I'm using? I didn't have to do that before I added the opengl stuff.

Comment: Your test project should link to those libraries. So it doesn't matter in which file you put it

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error maybe introduced by a type conflict.

> void GL::drawShape(Vector * points, ColorRGBA * colors, int size)

For above function declaration, you want to use the struct definition you created in your GLUtils, but the linker found those structure name already defined in other libraries and linked with them to create execution file for you.

To solve this error, you should tell linker explicit which definition you  want to use, such as the flowing.

```
void GL::drawShape(GL::Vector * points, GL::ColorRGBA * colors, int size)
```